# How to resolve the publishing changes from background threads is not allowed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been trying to create an application in swiftUI. Although my application is running properly but as soon as I run it in the emulator I am getting a message in my console stating that :-
2022-10-21 17:18:40.571733+0530 H4XOR News[87575:1413313] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Here's how my code looks like.

NetworkManager.swift:-

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
   @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                         let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            self.posts = results.hits
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

PostData.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable {
    let hits: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return objectID
    }
    let objectID: String
    let points: Int
    let title: String
    let url: String?
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.posts) { post in
                Text(post.title)
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("H4XOR NEWS")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Can anyone tell me why am I getting such message and how to resolve it.

Comment: you have a typo in your code, currently the `struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {...}`
  is inside the `struct ContentView: View {...}`, it should be outside.
 Note, DarkDust answer works well for me.  Also you may want to use `@StateObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()` in `ContentView`.

Answer (score 2):

As a side-effect of assigning your `posts` property in `self.posts = results.hits`, the `NetworkManager` is sending an event on its `objectWillChange` publisher (which is auto-generated as part of the [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) protocol). This happens on the same thread as the caller, and SwiftUI only wants this to happen on the main thread.

The completion handler of the data task is called on a background thread. And since you assign to `posts` on this thread, SwiftUI complains.

Simply dispatch to the main queue before assigning to this property:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.posts = results.hits
}
```

Comment: Getting H4XOR News[90937:1482676] [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. as a message in the console now

Comment: can you show on which line or lines of the code you get this error.

Comment: @AshutoshMukherjee: If you run your app in Xcode debugger and have breakpoints enabled, Xcode will break when this particular message is generated, IIRC. I seriously doubt it's related to this property.